# Is there a verb in the sentence 他说话的方式很奇怪?

Tags: grammar

I collect Chinese sentences which do not appear to have a verb, for comparison with other languages. (If you know a good source, or have some good examples, please let me know!)

Does this sentence contain a verb?

她说话的方式很奇怪。

To English I would write: She talks funny. or She has a strange way of talking.

Comment: I'll translate it as "The way he **speaks** is very strange", or "He **spoke** in a strange way". Am I wrong?

Comment: Not wrong, also a valid translation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**: The adjective 奇怪 is a predicate.  We can either think of the sentence as having no verb, or think of the verb as being part of the predicate.

This is an example of the grammar structure:

> Noun + 很 + Adj.
> <sub>[Simple "noun + adjective" sentences](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Simple_%22noun_%2B_adjective%22_sentences)</sub>

Here 很 is not regarded as a verb 动词, but as an adverb 副词.  So the sentence has no verb.  Or, we might otherwise think of [the verb being an innate part of the adjective](https://www.saporedicina.com/english/adjectives-in-chinese-grammar/):

> In Chinese, adjectives are called predicative adjectives because they have an intrinsic predicate value, in other words they posses the value given by the verb “to be”.

This deviates from English grammar, where [mostly we think of all sentences having verbs](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/87830/79987).

Instead of a verb, we have a [predicate 谓语](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Predicate).  I've encountered two definitions of "predicate", but the one I'm more used to is this one:

> 谓语 The Predicate
> The predicate makes a statement about the subject. The predicate is usually placed after the subject. ...
>
> When an adjective acts as the predicate the adverb 很 is usually used. Otherwise, a comparison is implied.
>
> 1. 这件毛衣很大。(This sweater is big.)
> 2. 这件毛衣大（那件合适）This sweater is big (that one is the right size)

Under this definition, 奇怪 is the predicate for 他说话的方式很奇怪.

[The Chinese Wikipedia](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%AC%82%E8%AA%9E) points out the two definitions:

> 1. 广义：传统语法当中，表示句子中主语以外的部分，与主语呈陈述关系。主语以外的名词短语也包括在内。
> 2. 狭义：现代语言学中，表示子句中的动词、形容词部分。名词短语不包括在内。

Answer (score 1):

First slice the sentence:

> 他    说话的方式             很奇怪
>
> his   way to talk   (is)   very strange.

Notice that the verb of this sentence is "is", but for a native Chinese speaker, we often omit the verb. If you insist to add the verb explicitly, you can try:他说话的方式是很奇怪的.

There are also some equivalent way to express same meaning:
他有奇怪的说话方式

Comment: I was thinking about 她说话。 “说话”是不是动词呢？